# Scala's @BeanProperty for Options

Tags: scala, jpa, javabeans

Is it possible to implement [BeanProperty](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/BeanProperty.html) for Optional variables? It would be useful with JPA.

It would be great if:

```
@BeanProperty var status: Option[String]
```

would add the following methods to the class:

```
def setStatus(s: String) { status = Some(s) }
def getStatus: String = status.get
```

Comment: If you are going to call `.get` on it, what's the point of using `Option`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, but there is a simple workaround that brings best of both worlds:

```
@BeanProperty
var status: String

def statusOption = Option(status)
```

Note that JPA does not understand `Option[T]`. BTW if you use field-access as opposed to getter/setter access in JPA, `@BeanProperty` isn't even needed - the JPA provider will scan Java fields instead.